# SQL Unpivot function returns smaller sum than original view

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am using the unpivot function but it is returning a smaller sum (2293) in the sum of [nulls destination_address] than the view where its pulling from (2692 is the correct one). So the unpivot is changing my results into a wrong number, but I dont know how to fix it. I tried cross all but couldnt make it work either.

```
SELECT
        [CLIENTDIVISION]
        ,[SHIP_ACT_PERIOD]
        ,[DATAFEED_WEEK]
        ,[BILL_SITE_ID]
        ,[CARRIERNAME]



--BELOW IS YOUR CATEGORIES 
,[TYPE_OF_NULL]  --This is a completely new column, does not exits. this is created during an unpivot.

--BELOW IS DATA THAT TIES TO THE CATEGORY.
,[NULLS COUNT]  --This is a completely new column, does not exits. this is created during an unpivot.


from [dbo].[BAS_CT_DATA_COMPLETENESS_vw1] --[TABLE HERE]

UNPIVOT
( [NULLS COUNT] for [TYPE_OF_NULL] in 

--WHAT YOU PUT IN PIVOT COLUMNS ARE THE CATEGORIES YOU WANT TO PIVOT ON

(
[nulls_INVOICEDBID]
,[nulls_INVOICESHIPMENTDBID]    
,[nulls_CLIENTLOCATION]
,[nulls_CLIENTDIVISION] 
,[nulls_CARRIERNAME]
,[nulls_INVOICENO]
,[nulls_SID]
,[nulls_SHIPMENTDATE]
,[nulls_PRODUCTION_DATE]
,[nulls_SERVICELEVELCODE]
,[nulls_SERVICELEVELNAME]
,[nulls_ORIGIN_ADDRESS]
,[nulls_ORIGINCITY]
,[nulls_ORIGINCOUNTRYCODE]
,[nulls_SHIPPERPOSTALCODE]
,[nulls_DESTINATION_ADDRESS]
,[nulls_DESTINATIONCITY]        
,[nulls_DESTINATIONCOUNTRYCODE]
,[nulls_CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE]
,[nulls_BILLINGCURRENCY]
,[nulls_INVOICEAMOUNT]
,[nulls_ACCESSORIAL_CODE]
,[nulls_ACCESSORIAL]
,[nulls_ACCESSORIAL_AMOUNT_LOC] 
,[nulls_IUOM_CHARGEKILOGRAMS]
,[nulls_REASON_CODE]
,[nulls_REASON_CODE_DESCRIPTION]
,[nulls_GL_CODE]

)) U

GROUP BY

U.[CLIENTDIVISION]
,U.[SHIP_ACT_PERIOD]
,U.[DATAFEED_WEEK]
,U.[BILL_SITE_ID]
,U.[CARRIERNAME]
,U.[TYPE_OF_NULL]
,U.[NULLS COUNT]





GO
```

Comment: Any reason you are doing a GROUP BY for all columns? This will be similar to a DISTINCT.

Comment: Are you sure that if you query the view with `WHERE [nulls destination_address] IS NOT NULL` and do the same 5-column GROUP BY the result isn't 2293, but 2692?

Comment: Ezlo you are my hero! It seems it was indeed the group by. Will test further, but for this example it worked. thank you!!!!!!